# exposing TCP service using nginx ingress controller operator on openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

We have nginx ingress controller installed on openshift using certified operator from openshift market place. We are trying to expose TCP service and trying to follow below document.

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/

But flag --tcp-services-configmap unable to add it do deployment either nginx ingress controller, when I add it to deployment it is not persisting because deployment is controlled by nginx ingress controller operator. I am not finding option to add flag --tcp-services-configmap in nginx ingress controller, is there any other way I can add this flag to nginx ingress controller?
Or any other way to expose TCP service using nginx ingress controller which is installed using operator.

Any inputs will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll want to open an issue with the operator repo that you did not link to in order for anyone to give you more concrete advice

Comment: @mdaniel Raised the issue nginx-ingress-controller operator git, hopefully will have some answers

Comment: Hi, I think we have some mismatch here. Assuming that you are talking about [nginx-ingress-operator](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-ingress-operator). The documentation that you are referencing is for the different product. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/nginx-ingress-controllers.md). From pure `nginx-ingress-inc` perspective, I'd reckon you should be looking here: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/transportserver-resource/ .

Comment: @DawidKruk Using nginx transportserver we are able to expose tcp service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For operator based nginx ingress controller exposing app over TCP below link will help to expose the app.

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/transportserver-resource/

**1. Modify the nginx ingress controller service to allow port 2222**

**2. Create globalconfiguration.**
**Example:** globalconfiguration.yaml

```
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1alpha1
kind: GlobalConfiguration
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-config
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  listeners:
  - name: ssh-tcp
    port: 2222
    protocol: TCP
```

**3. Create transportserver**
**Example:** transportserver-ssh-tcp.yaml

```
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1alpha1
kind: TransportServer
metadata:
  name: ssh-tcp
spec:
  listener:
    name: ssh-tcp
    protocol: TCP
  upstreams:
  - name: ssh-app
    service: ssh-server
    port: 22
  action:
    pass: ssh-app
```

Comment: Is there any way to point different subdomains of a domain (pointing to cluster's ip) to different services using tcp?